# Thumbnail description in gallery partially covered - float:left problem?

Tags: css, gallery

See http://jsfiddle.net/ZdjrT/  - The text under the first two thumbnails is partially obscured.

I can solve this if I set a height on the description, but obviously the description height is based on how much content is in there, so it's not a static value that I can set.

Is there another solution?

Thanks,
Wesley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the text is covered up is because it's so long that it overruns the 120px of height you explicitly set for `a.thumbnail`. The solution would be to get rid of that height declaration, but that could result in staggered rows that don't line up.

The solution for *that* is to use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`. Because you're only doing this on `a` elements, which are naturally inline, it should work in IE6+.

[Here's the fiddle to prove it](http://jsfiddle.net/vAtUN/) (note the `vertical-align:top`)

Comment: Did a bit more research, my example here was simplified. There is also a <div> inside the <a> in real world.. Does this mean that it won't work in IE due to not being inline?

Comment: @Wesley I don't know enough about IE6/7 to be able to say, but having a `div` inside an `a` is bad form, regardless. Can you update your code?

Comment: What's so bad about it? I need a link on an entire block of content.

Comment: @Wesley It's invalid, but more importantly (and possibly just as actually-not-a-big-deal) you're putting a block-level element inside an inline-level element. It's like crossing the streams.

Comment: But I have display:block in the css for a {} - you could probably fake it the other way around too, use spans and set to display:block - would that really make a difference.

Comment: @Wesley I think changing it to a span with `display:block` would have a much chance of working with IE6/7, if you do decide to use the `inline-block` method. But it's all just a matter of experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at this revision: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdjrT/5/
I made a.thumbnail display as an inline-block and removed the float. Changed the height to auto and then displayed the img as a block element. Seems to work in IE7/8, Chrome and FF.